# SQL - JOIN with condition CASE - how to make - if condition is met stop to meet next one

Tags: sql

Cashier can input to field C40_DATA 3 different values (9962**********, id_invoice, web_order)

what I would like to have as result:

1. if substr from C40_DATA contains p.id_invoice => show these lines
2. if C40_contains contains id_web_order or id_incvoice => show these lines
   -> it means point 1 shows always but point 2 -> do not show both, if exist id_web_order, show it and stop, if it not exists find id_incvoice

When I create this (below), result contains all 3 together, but I need 1 + (if exist 2 and if not find 3)

```
select * from web_data p
inner join POS_DATA re on
   (case 
      when substr(re.C40_DATA,5,8) = p.id_invoice and substr(re.C40_DATA,1,4) ='9962' then 1 else
       (case 
          when re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 1 else
           (case 
              when re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 1 else 0 END)
        END)
        END=1)
```

Could you please help how to make contitions in JOINs which do - if one condition is met stop and do not find the next one?

Thank you,

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the ON clause.

Comment: No need to nest. Just add a second `when`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @jarlh: I have already tried OR

Comment: select * from web_data p
inner join POS_DATA re on (
(
substr(re.C40_DATA,5,8) = p.id_invoice and substr(re.C40_DATA,1,4) ='9962')  
  or (re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order) 
  or (re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice)
)

Comment: same wrong result :-(

Comment: @shawnt00: where to add when? show show pls

Comment: @Tutanchamon, I offered an answer in case you hadn't checked back.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted query would have been better written this way:

```
select * from web_data p
    inner join POS_DATA re on
            substr(re.C40_DATA, 5, 8) = p.id_invoice and substr(re.C40_DATA, 1, 4) = '9962'            
        or  re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order and p.d_mnozstvi < '0'
        or  re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice   and p.d_mnozstvi < '0'
```

Had you really needed to do this as a `case` expression it could have been done as below. The cases fall through in order:

```
case
    when substr(re.C40_DATA, 5, 8) = p.id_invoice and substr(re.C40_DATA, 1, 4) ='9962' then 1
    when re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 1
    when re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice   and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 1
end = 1
```

As far as matching only on a single condition, I think you want something like this:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case
            when re.C40_DATA = '9962' + p.id_invoice then 1
            when re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 2
            when re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice   and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 3
        end as match_rank,
        min(case
            when re.C40_DATA = '9962' + p.id_invoice then 1
            when re.C40_DATA = p.id_web_order and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 2 
            when re.C40_DATA = p.id_invoice   and p.d_mnozstvi < '0' then 3
        ) over (partition by p.id_invoice, p.web_order) as min_match_rank
    from web_data p
        inner join POS_DATA re on
                re.C40_DATA = '9962' + p.id_invoice
            or  re.C40_DATA = (p.id_web_order, p.id_invoice) and p.d_mnozstvi < '0'

)
select * from data where match_rank = min_match_rank;
```

I've taken the liberty of rewriting some of your conditions in case those options are useful to you. Also, I'm not sure what  `< '0'` is supposed to mean. Finally, I'm not sure which values to be partitioning over because I don't understand the relationship between `id_invoice` and `id_web_order`.